# Python: read text variable line by line (not file)

Tags: python

I do have:

```
url="https://mywebpage.com/content"
text=requests.get(url,stream=True).text

for line in text:
  print "Line "+line
```

I got each letter in a different line (instead of line).
I also can not use iterator req.iter_lines because I need to process the results multiple times looking for different data.

Any hints?

Comment: `for line in text.split('\n'):`...

Comment: As soon as you access `.text` on the stream object - it retrieves the entire lot anyway... you might as well just do `text = requests.get(url).text.splitlines()` to get a list of lines...

Comment: *I also can not use iterator req.iter_lines because i need to process the results multiple times looking for different data.* - Is retrieving a line each time and then performing the multiple checks on each line not feasible then? (as opposed to getting all the lines, looping over it to check for something once, then looping over it again to check something else?)

Answer (score 5):

You should use `split` and `strip`, in case you have windows style line breaks (`\r`)

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
  line = line.strip('\r')
  print ("Line "+line)
```